# layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Можно реализовать в коде layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf? То есть настроить расположение элементов в определенном порядке динамически.

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите изменять constraints в коде. Для этого вам понадобиться `ConstraintSet`

Пример реализации:

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

// Это нужно если вы хотите сохранить constraints которые есть в xml
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);

//Идентично app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" 

constraintSet.connect(R.id.button1, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.button2, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)

// Применяете данные constraints к ConstraintLayout
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```